# Simple SQL query lasts forever

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am using `mysql-workbench` and `mysql` server in `ubunt 18` machine with 16 GB RAM.

I have a schema named `ips`, and two tables, say: `table1` and `table2`.
In `table1` and `table2` there are two fields: `ip` and `description`, bit are of type string. I have a lot of record. `table1` has 779938 records and `table2` has 136657 records.

I need to make a joint query to find the number of `ip`s in `table2` that has a `description` starts with `str1%` and does not contains `str2` and does not contains `str3`. In the same time, those `ip`s has a description in `table1` that does not start with `str1%`, and contains either `str2` or `str3`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`table2`.`ip`)
FROM `ips`.`table2`, `ips`.`table1`
WHERE `table2`.`ip` = `table1`.`ip`
       AND (LOWER(`table1`.`description`) NOT LIKE 'str1%' 
             AND (LOWER(`tabl1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str2-%' 
                   OR LOWER(`table1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str3-%'
                 )
            )
       AND (LOWER(`table2`.`description`) LIKE 'str1%'
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str2-%' 
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str3-%'
           );
```

However, the query never ends. The duration has `?` and I never get result. Can you please help?

**EDIT:**

Here are the SHOW CREATE TABLE and

1) `SHOW CREATE TABLE`ips`.`table2`;`

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `ip` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

2) `SHOW CREATE TABLE`ips`.`table1`;`

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `ip` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

3) `EXPLAIN <query>`

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, table2, , ALL, , , , , 136109, 100.00, Using where
1, SIMPLE, table1, , ALL, , , , , 786072, 10.00, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

**EDIT 2:**

The data for `ip` field are string in this format: `str.str.str.str`
The `decription` field is in this format: `str1-str2-str3-str4`

Comment: Side note: You using a old comma join syntax beter is to use `INNER JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.. Question about query performance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output for every table involved in the query and the output off `EXPLAIN <query>`... the SQL server tag should be removed because backticks are MySQL syntax only

Comment: As well as the `EXPLAIN`, asked for in the comment above, please could you also confirm what indexes you have on the table, and whether you can create new ones?

Comment: Does description field follow any format on how values are stored? Could you also show sample data, could try to rewrite query based on how data is stored to avoid checking same column multiple times.

Comment: Oh i now notice now you use functions (`LOWER()`) those can't be indexed unless you going to make a **STORED** generated column ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html ) but you need atleast MySQL 5.7

Comment: .. also if you use a case insensitive  charset ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html ) on your table or column (`COLLATE`) you can avoid using `LOWER()` when comparing with `LIKE 'str1%'`... Most of the time the charsets or collates end with `_ci` so you know they are case insensitive

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  check my updates please. I use `5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Comment: Just a note about your logic : `'aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd' LIKE '%-ddd-%'` won't be a match, even though it appears that you think it should be?  Things can be optimised further by storing each of those four strings in a separate column.

Comment: Your tables have no primary keys and no unique constraints. So one `ip` can appear multiple times in `table1` and multiple times in `table2`. How about real data? Is it okay for an `ip` to appear multiple times in the tables? Or should it be unique in one or both of them?

Comment: There is no foreign key either. So it is possible that `table1` has many, many `ips` and `table2` has an awful lot, too, but no `ip` appears in both tables. Is this desired? Or must each `ip` in `table1` also appear in `table2` or vice versa?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  I thank you as your comments helped me. As I said in your deleted comment, I solved it by marking `ip` as primary key (`PK`), and unique (`UQ`), and not null (`NN`). I think `PK` is the missing thing that caused the problem. In my case, the field `ip` is unique for each row so it can act as `PK`. I just forgot to make `PK` from the beginning. I use mysql-workebench and all this done without writing statement, just check boxes from `Alter table` by right clicking the tables.

Comment: `ip` is unique in `table1` or `table2` or both?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner in both. It can be repeated in different tables (that's why I do join) but not in the single table level. For example, 1.1.1.1 is an ip which can be found in the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer regarding Indexing might optimise the query. It might be correct. But I am sorry that I have to check the answer I used to solve the problem. Thanks to @Raymond Nijland for being first to point the indexing issue which reminded me of the primary keys.

The source of the problem is that both tables in the query did not have primary key. The primary key must be for a key that is unique and not null. In my case I already have the `ip` field ready to server as the primary key. Since I use `mysql- workbench` I right click the tables, click `Alter Table` then check the primary key for the approperiate field as follows:

[image]

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `ALL` operator in the execution plan because the SQL planner is not using any index. It's performing a Full Table Scan on both tables.

A Full Table Scan can be optimal when you are selecting more than 5% of the rows. In your case this could be good if your string prefix "str1" had a single letter. If it has more than one character, then the usage on an index could greatly improve the performance.

Now, the comparisong you are performing is not a simple one. You are not comparing the value of a column, but the result of an expression: `LOWER(table1.description)`. Therefore you need to create virtual columns and index them if you want this query to be fast. This is available on MySQL 5.7 and newer:

```
alter table table1 add lower_desc varchar(50) 
  generated always as (LOWER(description)) virtual;
create index ix1 on table1 (lower_desc);

alter table table2 add lower_desc varchar(50) 
  generated always as (LOWER(description)) virtual;
create index ix2 on table2 (lower_desc);
```

These indexes will make your queries faster when the prefix has two or more characters. Get the execution plan again. Now, the operators `ALL` should not be there anymore (`INDEX` operators should show up in their place now).

Incidentally, I think your missed a join in the query. I think it should look like (I added the third line):

```
SELECT COUNT(`table2`.`ip`)
FROM `ips`.`table2`
JOIN `ips`.`table1` on `ips`.`table1`.ip = `ips`.`table2`.ip
WHERE `table2`.`ip` = `table1`.`ip`
       AND (LOWER(`table1`.`description`) NOT LIKE 'str1%' 
             AND (LOWER(`tabl1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str2-%' 
                   OR LOWER(`table1`.`description`) LIKE '%-str3-%'
                 )
            )
       AND (LOWER(`table2`.`description`) LIKE 'str1%'
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str2-%' 
            AND LOWER(`table2`.`description`) NOT LIKE '%-str3-%'
           );
```

Also, to optimize the join performance you'll need one (or both) of the indexes shown below:

```
create index ix3 on table1 (ip);
create index ix4 on table2 (ip);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm sorry, my bad. MySQL 5.7 supports indexes on virtual columns, as a workaround. Fixed the explanation.

Comment: "MySQL 5.7 supports indexes on virtual columns, as a workaround. " they need to be stored not virtaul..

Comment: I guess you may be talking about MariaDB. In MariaDB only persistent columns can be indexed. I think MySQL allow stored and virtual columns to be indexed. Lemme check.

Comment: Only when InnoDB is used, InnoDb supports virtual type also to be indexed.

Comment: Ah... interesting. I didn't know that. I guess I always use InnoDB only. Well, @
user9371654 uses InnoDB... phew... saved by the bell ;-)

Comment: Another option would be to use a case-insensitive collation for the `description` column, then it's not necessary to call `LOWER()` in the first place.

Comment: It should also be noted that `LIKE` can't use an index when the pattern begins with `%`.

Comment: I'm with Barmer here. Indexes on the descriptions are no help, as we need full scans on both tables anyway. So it's all about the join then, i.e. indexes on the `ip` columns.

Comment: I think Full Table Scans are not really needed since the main search patterns don't start with a `%`. Index Range Scans should be useful. Well, in any case a simple test will tell.